# Missing files after VSTS Migration with Opshub

Tags: opshub

I just completed a migration using OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility and it completed 'successfully'.

We tested our CI builds and they failed due to missing files, we have compared the source TFS to the target VSTS and found that there are files missing in VSTS.

We are using version v2.0.0.002 of the migration utility.

Comment: Can you please share logs to ovsmu@opshub.com [Zip the "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\logs" directory and send it]. Also can you analyse the change set history, to get from which change set the files were missed. What was the operation in that change set.

Comment: Logs emailed. I deleted the VSTS team project and ran the source code migration again and it worked.

Comment: From memory the change set for the files was a Branch.

The work item migration configuration is giving an error with the template mismatch for Code Review Response > Reviewed By field (Scrum template).  This has been reported in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244528/free-migration-tool-not-working-with-standard-agile-template by another user.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not getting reproduced with the latest release of the utility version  2.0.0.004 available at -
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2