# Free migration tool not working with standard agile template

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

The OpsHub free migration tool recently updated to version 2.  This stripped much functionality out of the tool which I am trying to workaround.  But I can't get passed the process validation, as it is complaining about the Code Review work item have a reviewed by field.  We are using the agile process template in TFS 2013.4 with no customisation, any help to get passed this newly introduced blocker would be much appreciated.
[image: Image showing error message in OpsHub Migration Tool]

Comment: Does this issue occur with old version?

Comment: Hi Eddie, no the last version of the utility passed this validation ok only a week earlier.  This WIT has never been modified by the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it indicates that the "Reviewed By" field has been customized, you can try to download the default process template from "Visual Studio\Team\Team Project Collection Settings\Process Template Manager" and then import the "CodeReviewResponse.xml" WIT XML definition files using [witadmin importwitd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd312129.aspx) command.

Comment: Thanks Eddie, I have imported the type to make sure it is not customised as suggested.  It still gives the validation error.  We are using Agile 2013.4 Process.  The strange thing is it works for another project I have just tried....I will try deleting the VSO Team Project and see if recreating that fixes things.

Comment: OK, project2 passed the validation.  For the troublesome project1 I re-created the VSO Team Project...same error.  So for project2, I deleted that on VSO and created again, tried the migration which failed on the same validation.  So it appears something has changed with how agile projects are created on VSO in the past week or two that is actually the issue here.  Any thoughts very welcome.

Comment: I got an email from OpsHub this morning confirming Microsoft have changed the Template online, they are hoping to have an update on Wednesday for this.  Thanks again for your help Eddie.

Comment: Has there been an update on this at all? Trying to do a couple of migrations myself using the ops hub tool using the default Agile and Scrums templates.

Comment: Connel, OpsHub updated the utility back in December when they found out Microsoft had changed things online which cleared this error for me.