# OpsHub TFS 2010 to Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

When trying to migrate from TFS 2010 to Visual studio online via OpsHub getting the error below

```
Template Customization or template mismatch Error

Code Review Response
   Reviewed By
```

[[image: ScreenShot of the error][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHhhH.png)

Comment: There is a same question asked in SO, refer to this link for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244528/free-migration-tool-not-working-with-standard-agile-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a change in VSTS by Microsoft. The 'Review By' field has been removed. OpsHub will be releasing a patch to handle this change by this weekend.

We regret the inconvenience caused.

Comment: OpsHub has released its new version OVSMU-V2.0.0.003 which handle this change. It can be downloaded from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2

Comment: I'm having same issue with OVSMU-V2.0.0.004

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue with the 12/28 update
VERSION 2.0.0.002. 
There are no WIT customizations for Code Review Response.

Comment: Hi the release with version 2.0.0.003 has the fix. Please use that version.