# OpsHub v2.0.0.004 Template Mismatch on standard Scrum Process template

Tags: templates, tfs, opshub, azure-devops

I've found a couple of similar questions on Stackoverflow, but the answers do not solve my issue. (For example the issue would be fixed in previous version. [OpsHub TFS 2010 to Visual Studio Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253022/opshub-tfs-2010-to-visual-studio-online))
Also I experience different behaviors on multiple environments so I think it's a new question. I hope someone can help me.

I have some projects on a TFS 2012 with the standard Scrum 2.2 template. I created a Visual Studio Team Services environment on my personal account for testing the migration. I created a project based on the default Scum process with the same name as the project in TFS. When I use the OpsHub tool (version 2.0.0.004) to migrate the work items to VSTS it works as expected.
[screenshot of working migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4qYa.png)

Now I create a new project on my companies VSTS environment with the same name and the same Scrum template. Apply the same rights, and try to migrate the same project to companies VSTS, validation fails with the message that "template customization or template mismatch". Details "Code Review Response - Reviewed By"
[screenshot of failed validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LJfM.png)

I exported the scrum process templates for both environments and compared the contents but they are identical.
So I have 1 project on TFS and 2 projects on VSTS with identical templates. One migration works, the other does not. I'm stuck. Any tips would be very welcome!
Thanx

Comment: Export the process templates for the two projects on VSTS and check if there is any difference between them.

Comment: Hi Eddie,
Thank you for your help. I did export the templates and compared the contents, but they are identical.

Comment: Hey, we are working with Microsoft to address this issue. Please give us some time to get back.

Comment: Great, thank you! If I need to provide more info, credentials, or something else. Please let me know.

Comment: Hi, I found this post after just attempting our first migration. Running TFS 2013 with default scrum template, and attempting to migrate to VSTS also with default scrum template. Get same validation message. Hopefully this can be sorted out very soon! Running v2.0.0.004. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an email from OpsHub with the solution! They released a new version (2.0.0.005) and after clearing the cache, it works! Thank you, OpsHub.

Refer [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2) to download the latest version.

Perform following steps:

- Close the OVSMU Tool if running.
- Installed the latest version OVSMU-V2.0.0.005
- Clear the following cache folder:
- Close the OVSMU Tool as well as any instances of Visual Studio (ie. TFS related applications)
- Clear the contents of the following folders (whichever ones you have)
          %localappdata%/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/3.0/Cache
          %localappdata%/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/4.0/Cache
          %localappdata%/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/5.0/Cache
          %localappdata%/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/6.0/Cache
- Launch the newly installed OVSMU Tool & Configure the migration again.