# OpsHub Scrum template mismatch

Tags: visual-studio, opshub

I am trying to migrate a TFS 2015 Scrum project to VSTS. I successfully migrated this project in December 2015. 
Two days ago I deleted the target project in VSTS and attempted to migrate the same project again.
This time, I get a validation error:

[image]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244528/free-migration-tool-not-working-with-standard-agile-template?s=1%7C0.4667) has raised a similar issue, but there is no clear answer as the OP noted that OpsHub has indicated that there is a known issue with Microsoft making a change to how VSTS projects are created, but there was no indication of when this would be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a recent change done in VSTS by Microsoft. The [latest version](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2) of the migration utility handles this change. Please verify that you are using the latest version (ie. v2.0.0.003 or higher)

Comment: I installed version 2.0.0.004 today. I then created a new TFS scrum project, a new VSTS Scrum project. I tried to migrate and got the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I created a new TFS scrum project **and** a new VSTS project.

Comment: Hi, we just want to confirm to be sure. The VSTS project is using the DEFAULT scrum template right? Can you export the Template XML and share them with us at ovsmu@opshub.com?

Comment: Thanks - sent the template XML by email.

Comment: I replied to your email suggestion. Didn't receive a reply so assume that I have to ping you on StackOverflow.

Comment: We are verifying the issue at our end. Please give us some time to get back to you.

Comment: I sent another email this morning before I saw this comment.

Comment: Has there been an update on this? Running version 2.0.0.004 of the tool and getting this error when I try to migrate projects using the default SCRUM and Agile templates.

Comment: 2.0.0.005 has this fixed for SCRUM template. What is the mismatch that you are getting for Agile projects?